# Portable char newline

Tags: c++, c, qt, stream, newline

Is there a way to write a cross-platform parser that reads chars until a newline character is found? I'm using '\0' in Linux, but I'm not sure that this can be done on Windows too.

```
std::string line;
// fill the line
QTextStream ss(&line);

for(;;)
{
    ss >> c;
    if(c == '"' || c=='\0' ) // here I want to continue parsing until a new-line character or a ending double quote is found 
        break;
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `\0` is not a newline, right?

Comment: You can't use `std::getline` first to get a line from the stream and then parse that?

Comment: If you're doing formatted input with standard streams, then `'\n'` is your thing... I'd guess it's the same with Qt.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with the C++ text streams (`std::istream` and `std::ostream`, unless the `ios_base::binary` flag has been set when opening a file stream), then C++ treats input and output of `\n` in a platform-independent manner.

That means that reading a file which contains `\r\n` on Windows will treat this as if it were `\n`, and likewise outputting `\n` will output a platform-specific newline character.

If you need to read consecutive lines, the easiest way is to use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string line;
while (getline(std::cin, line)) {
    // process line
}
```

`\0` is **never** treated as a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

The newline character in C is '\n' not '\0'.  It will be converted to whatever the current platform uses.

Comment: @UmNyobe Isn't the standard library supposed to transparently 'translate' it?

Comment: he is using Qt. I assume it behaves as the std library, but I don't have solid proof. But it is good to mention, isn't it?